# Vue.set() and push() for Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a mutator that attempts to make the follow update:

`state.forms[1].data.metrics.push(newArrayItem)`

- `forms` is an object with `1` as a key
- `metrics` is an array

For some reason, Vuex successfully updates, but components don't react to this change.
I was reading about `Vue.set()` on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

But I'm not sure how to apply it, or even if it's the right answer at all here.

Thanks for the help.

`this.$forceUpdate` is working, which is a bit strange because the component loading the data uses `computed` properties.

Form state is setup initially like so:

```
const state = {
  forms: {}
};
```

New forms are pushed like so:

```
state.forms[id] = { formName: payload.formName, data: {metrics: []}};
```

And new metrics are added like so:

```
var result = getParent(state, payload.path);

result.metricParent.data.metrics.push({ id: newMetricId(state, result.formId), ...payload.metric });
```

Comment: Can you post how state data is setup initially?

Comment: I added details. Also, I have a list of forms, and it worked when I would only have one form in the store, it's when I added that "forms" object when things broke. Is it a better idea here to use dynamic modules and just load one form at time?

Comment: If at any point you are mutating the data in a way that Vue cannot observe, then it can result in mutations that don't update the view. See [change detection caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). For example, `state.forms[id] = ...` is already a violation.

Comment: @DecadeMoon right, I'm aware of that, the issue is that I'm not sure how to combine the fix (using Vue.set for arrays) when I need to push to the metrics array while accessing it through the forms array. I think I solved my problem using dynamic modules, but if you have a good idea how to combine these let me know. I even tried recreating the array, pushing, and then assigning to state.forms[index], but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not with pushing to arrays. Your problem is in this line:

```
state.forms[id] = { formName: payload.formName, data: {metrics: []}};
```

Because you are creating a new property of `state.forms` without using `Vue.set()`, the form is not reactive, so when you push to the metrics array later, it's not recognized.

Instead, you should do this:

```
Vue.set(state.forms, id, { formName: payload.formName, data: {metrics: []}});
```

Then, pushing to `state.forms[id].data.metrics` should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Vue setup reactive data looking for how the state/data is setup, by example if in a regular component you define the data like `{x: {y: 10}}` and you change the data somehow `this.x.y = 20;` it’s going to work, because Vue make the object with that structure reactive (because is the setup structure) based on that if you try to do, `this.x.z = 10;` not works because “z” not exists, and you need to tell to Vue that you need to make it reactive, this is when `this.$set(this.x, “z”, 10);` enters, it’s basically saying “make this data reference in position ‘z’ reactive”, after this point direct calls to `this.x.z = ?` works, in vuex the same happens, use `Vue.set(state.forms, 1,  { formName: payload.formName, data: {metrics: []}});` after that the reference to `state.forms[1]` (including sub data) is now reactive!

Comment: When you use arrays, and setup it to initial state, every call to push method is reactive, and don’t need to manually use Vue.set(), in objects is necessary because it’s not possible to track new object properties additions in vue 2